# Laravel how to create foreign key constrain from non-primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table named `header`

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('restaurant_number')->unsigned();
$table->integer('transaction_id')->unsigned()->unique(); <-- Right here
```

On [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) it says

> Laravel also provides support for creating foreign key constraints,
>   which are used to force referential integrity at the database level.
>   For example, let's define a user_id column on the posts table that
>   references the id column on a users table:

But on my `details` table I referencing the transaction_id from header which is not primary key and I got error this error `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`. How can reference it from a non-primary

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('restaurant_number')->unsigned();
$table->integer('transaction_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('transaction_id')->references('transaction_id')->on('header');
```

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: @RimonKhan yes (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: what is your laravel version

Comment: @RimonKhan I'm using latest version 5.5

Comment: can you show me full migration file?/

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot list of your migration files? @BGTabulationBGTabulate

Comment: @BGTabulationBGTabulate what database lib are you using? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is because both table as to be of the exact same types. I can see that in the second table the field is nullable and in the first is not. Maybe this is the problem